# NSArray Help for breaking information

Tags: iphone, json, nsarray

Hi
i am getting one response from the server "{\"bindings\":[{\"Latitude\":\"25.451808633333332\",\"Longitude\":\"81.83372523333333\"}]}" , it is in array, i need to break the latitude and longitude part or values and initialize the value into another string.

Comment: This looks more like JSON than an NSArray

Comment: yes it is in json , however values are not coming in dictionary, it is coming in array.

Comment: http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *latitudeString = [[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"bindings"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
NSString *longitudeString = [[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"bindings"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Longitude"];
```

In more nice way:

```
NSDictionary *gealocationDict = [[jsonDict objectForKey:@"bindings"]objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *latitudeString  = [gealocationDict objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
NSString *longitudeString = [gealocationDict bjectForKey:@"Longitude"];
```

Comment: thanks for the information,however i have previously mentioned that the information from the server is coming in array not in dictionary.

Comment: If that string you provide is the response from the server that is and dictionary. Paste the response string and i will edit my post. The dictionary starts with "{" and the array starts with "[".